# Add button for full screen video with exo player

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using exoPlayer to stream video to my app and so far works fine. What I would like to do now is to add some extra functionality such as a button on the bottom right edge to act as a "full screen button".

But there are two problems. The first is that `ExoPlayer` doesn't seems to provide any Control class so you can simple add a button and override its functionality. 
What I guess is that I have to display that button on top of the video so I might have to wrap both in a `FrameLayout` and add gravity = bottom for the button or is there another way ?

The second problem is : if user clicks the full screen button what should I do next? Add another `Fragment` with the video view in full screen ? But how can I start the video from the point it was when user click the button and not start it from the beginning ?  I cant find in exoPlayer anything relative to start from a specific time.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `SimpleExoPlayerView`, there is a way to customize the Player's view, especially the Control's view. Check the documentation of `SimpleExoPlayerView`:

> **Attributes**
>
> The following attributes can be set on a `SimpleExoPlayerView` when used in a layout XML file:
>   ...
>
> *controller_layout_id* - Specifies the id of the layout resource to be inflated by the child `PlaybackControlView`. See below for more details.
>
> - Corresponding method: None
> - Default: *R.id.exo_playback_control_view*
>
> ...

So basically you can provide your own layout file for the controller (you can copy the *exo_playback_control_view* layout mentioned in the docs, which is the default one, and customize that as you want. **Note** that you'll need to provide the same view ids for the existing controls (so it's best to actually copy that), as mentioned in the docs of `PlaybackControlView`:

> **Overriding the layout file**
>
> To customize the layout of `PlaybackControlView` throughout your app, or just for certain configurations, you can define *exo_playback_control_view.xml* layout files in your application res/layout* directories. These layouts will override the one provided by the *ExoPlayer* library, and will be inflated for use by `PlaybackControlView`. The view identifies and binds its children by looking for the following ids:
>
> - *exo_play* - The play button.
> - *exo_pause* - The pause button.
> - *exo_ffwd* - The fast forward button.
> - *exo_rew* - The rewind button.
> - *exo_prev* - The previous track button.
> - *exo_next* - The next track button.
> - *exo_position* - Text view displaying the current playback position.
> - *exo_duration* - Text view displaying the current media duration.
> - *exo_progress* - Seek bar that's updated during playback and allows seeking.
>
> All child views are optional and so can be omitted if not required, however where defined they must be of the expected type.

Below is the customized layout with fullscreen button. You get the reference to the button by `view.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button)` and attach the `OnClickListener` to the button. Inside `onClick()` you can start your full screen activity (you can define it's full screen either in the *AndroidManifest.xml* or programatically) or show another fragment, that has the `SimpleExoPlayerView` occupying the whole screen.
As of your second point you can get the playback position like this: `playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition()`and pass it to the new full screen Activity/Fragment as an Intent extra. Then, in that full screen Activity/Fragment you load the video, extract that `playbackPosition` value and call:

```
player.seekTo(playbackPosition);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Here is the control layout file:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    // This is the custom button
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen_button"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    <SeekBar android:id="@id/exo_progress"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="32dp"
      android:focusable="false"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great answer, I was trying to get the PlaybackControlView and then with that view get each button and this throwed a null reference, I tried with your answer and worked fine, instead of using the PlaybackControlView I used the main activity view to find the  buttons.

Answer (score 7):

## Solution with a new full screen Activity on top of the current one, passing the playback position to it

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286792/4034572) is great and points you in the right direction, but it's rather theoretical, and I still had to fill some gaps and solve a few things when writing the code. I'll try to complement it.

Start by copying the layout `exo_playback_control_view.xml` from the ExoPlayer library to `res/layout`. File link: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml

Modify the layout to add the full screen button, which can be something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen_button"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_expand"
        android:focusable="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that you can have different layouts for different `PlayerView`s by using the attribute `app:controller_layout_id`. You can also remove player buttons if you don't want them. This is covered in the docs: https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html#overriding-layout-files

Once you have the full screen button, set an `OnClickListener` on it:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button).setOnClickListener {
    player.playWhenReady = false // pause current video if it's playing
    startActivity(
        FullScreenVideoActivity.newIntent(
            context,
            videoUrl,
            player.currentPosition
        )
    )
}
```

Add the `FullScreenVideoActivity`:

```
private const val EXTRA_VIDEO_URL = "EXTRA_VIDEO_URL"
private const val EXTRA_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS = "EXTRA_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS"

private const val STATE_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS = "STATE_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS"

class FullScreenVideoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun newIntent(packageContext: Context, videoUrl: String, playbackPositionMs: Long): Intent {
            val intent =
                Intent(packageContext, FullScreenVideoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_URL, videoUrl)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS, playbackPositionMs)
            return intent
        }
    }

    private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_video)

        val videoUrl = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_URL)
        var playbackPositionMs = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS, 0)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // The user rotated the screen
            playbackPositionMs = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS)
        }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button).setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        val playerView: PlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name))
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent)
        val mediaSource: MediaSource =
            ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
        player.prepare(mediaSource)
        player.seekTo(playbackPositionMs)
        player.playWhenReady = true
        playerView.player = player
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        player.playWhenReady = false
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        player.release()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putLong(STATE_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MS, player.currentPosition)
    }

}
```

Add the activity to the Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.FullScreenVideoActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" <-- this is optional
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
```

Finally add the theme to `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

That's all! Hope it helps.

## Alternative solution in current Activity

The above solution works fine and it's trivial. However it requires re-downloading bits of the video you've already downloaded, which interrupts the playback :/

I've been trying to avoid this by following [this directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511657/4034572). This is what I have so far:

```
activity!!.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
val fullScreenPlayerView = PlayerView(context)
val dialog = object : Dialog(context!!, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        activity!!.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        PlayerView.switchTargetView(player, fullScreenPlayerView, playerView)
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
dialog.addContentView(
    fullScreenPlayerView,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
)
dialog.show()
PlayerView.switchTargetView(player, playerView, fullScreenPlayerView)
```

Note that for this to work you have to set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"` to your Activity in the Manifest.

Comment: thank you Albert. You saved me from doing a lot of work. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can now display a full screen button by setting a click listener on the `StyledPlayerView`:

```
videoPlayer.setFullscreenButtonClickListener {}
```

Where the view is:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView/>
```

Comment: Sharing my code using your solution, thanks:
https://pastebin.com/thHPkfM6

Answer (score 0):

I made a kotlin extension function for that.
You need two Exoplayer and the extension will switch between the two players (fullscreen and normal).

```
    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
fun SimpleExoPlayer.preparePlayer(playerView: PlayerView, playerViewFullscreen: PlayerView) {

    (playerView.context as AppCompatActivity).apply {
        val fullScreenButton: ImageView = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon)
        val normalScreenButton: ImageView = playerViewFullscreen.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon)
        fullScreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_open))
        normalScreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_close))

        fullScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
            supportActionBar?.hide()
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            playerView.visibility = View.GONE
            playerViewFullscreen.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            PlayerView.switchTargetView(this@preparePlayer, playerView, playerViewFullscreen)
        }

        normalScreenButton.setOnClickListener {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
            supportActionBar?.show()
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            normalScreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_close))
            playerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            playerViewFullscreen.visibility = View.GONE
            PlayerView.switchTargetView(this@preparePlayer, playerViewFullscreen, playerView)
        }

        playerView.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT
        playerView.player = this@preparePlayer
    }

}

fun SimpleExoPlayer.setSource(context: Context, url: String){
    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "app"))
    val videoSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
    this.prepare(videoSource)
}
```

For example with this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="300dp">

          <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
              android:id="@+id/playerView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     </RelativeLayout>

     <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
         android:id="@+id/playerViewFullscreen"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use it like this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val player: SimpleExoPlayer by lazy { SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext).build() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        player.preparePlayer(playerView, playerViewFullscreen)
        player.setSource(applicationContext, "http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4")
        player.playWhenReady = true
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        player.playWhenReady = false
    }

    public override fun onDestroy() {
        player.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

If you prefer not copy this code, you can add this lib. It do the same : https://github.com/Norulab/android-exoplayer-fullscreen