# How to play video only in portrait mode using exo player for android?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I am using exo player in my android app to play video from server.
Video play in portrait mode for lollipop+, but for kitkat version video play in landscape mode.

Following is the code

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, null, getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerExample"));

    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
            uri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

    MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(
            this, sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(
            sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
    player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);

    player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
    player.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add button for full screen video with exo player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990193/add-button-for-full-screen-video-with-exo-player)