# overriding exoplayer controller gives Error:(27, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_next')

Tags: android, xml, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to add a fullscreen button to exoPlayer controls.
I've created an xml file with the name

> exo_playback_control_view.xml

acording to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990193/add-button-for-full-screen-video-with-exo-player)

but it gives me a whole set of errors i don't know how to solve

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    // This is the custom button
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen_button"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    <SeekBar android:id="@id/exo_progress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and these are the errors i get

```
Error:(15, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_rew').
Error:(18, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_play').
Error:(19, 20) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/ExoMediaButton.Play').
Error:(21, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_pause').
Error:(22, 20) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause').
Error:(24, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_ffwd').
Error:(27, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_next').
Error:(44, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_position').
Error:(54, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_progress').
Error:(61, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/exo_duration').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

what can i do OR how can i implement anew button to the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nearestPhoneIV"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:src="@drawable/phone"/>
```

id should be `"@+id/idname"`

Comment: Thats great! but what about the style that shows an error

Comment: i found the answer to the style

It doesn't inflate the player.
the app crashes.

Comment: Check if you have that style defined in your styles.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/exo_position"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>
```

@id/exo_position use to reuse the id of a view while @+id/exo_position use to declare a new view id.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style name="CustomExoMediaButton">
   <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
   <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/video_view_exo_player_play_pause_button_dimen</item>
   <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/video_view_exo_player_play_pause_button_dimen</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomExoMediaButton.Play">
   <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_play_circle_filled</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomExoMediaButton.Pause">
   <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_pause_circle_filled</item>
</style>
```

Refer to this [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5573-media-playback-on-android-with-exoplayer-getting-started) for what you implementing.

Happy coding:)